# this.context is null in jest/Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a react class without anything to render. It has few function which uses `const name = { this.context }` inside a function. However, `name` (in below example) is always undefined. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have tried setting context `wrap.setContenxt({name: true})` but still when the function is called it shows `this.context` as `{}`.

person.js

```
export class Person extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  someMethod() {
    const { name } = this.context;
    const { record } = this.props;

    if (record && name) {
      this.setState({
        awesome: true
      });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {}

  render() {
    return null
  }
}
```

test.js

```
describe("this.context test", () => {

  const props = { record: true }
  const context = { name: false }

  it('should test someMethod()', () => {
    const wrap = shallow( <Person {...props} />, {context})
    const instance = wrap.instance()

    instance.someMethod();
    expect(instance.state.awesome).toBe(true) // pass

  })   
});
```

I expect that it should not set state since `name` is `false`

**Update:**
One of thing I missed from documentation is:

> The root component you are rendering must have a `contextTypes` static property.

Based on that if I update test.js as follow, it works:

```
describe("this.context test", () => {
   // ***this was missing***
   Person.contextTypes = {
      name: PropTypes.boolean
   };

  const props = { record: true }
  const context = { name: false }

  it('should test someMethod()', () => {
    const wrap = shallow( <Person {...props} />, {context})
    const instance = wrap.instance()

    instance.someMethod();
    expect(instance.state.awesome).toBe(true) // fail

  })   
});
```